# Deserializing C++ string in WCF service using Json converter

Tags: c++, string, wcf, utf-8, json-deserialization

I am trying to communicate with C# wcf service which takes josn as an input where json contains image data, i wrote C# client where I am converting the object (InputData) which contains image as byte[] to json and sending it to server.

```
Client side:
 InputData  RequestData; //copied image data into RequestData obj 
 String jsonRequest = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(RequestData); //converting obj to json

where : 
    public class InputData
    {
        private byte[] RawImage = null;
        public byte[] FrontImage 
        {
            get return this.FrontRawImage;
            set if (null != value) { FrontRawImage = value.ToArray(); }
         }
     }


Server side: 
       //deserialize and get the object 
       InputData requestData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputData>(jsonData);
```

I am able to do this with C# client but the problem is, I have to communicate this WCF service from C++ client where I am converting image(jpg) data to string **(utf-8)**and then creating json and sending it to the service but on server side I am not able deserialze this json to InputData object (returning null with an exception unexpected characters).

//I am getting an exception on server side that says "unexpected character in the requested data"
InputData requestData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);

I debug in the server side =>
 json request data from c# client looks like

> "{\"Image\":[92,34,92,34,36,73, 56.......huge image data here]}"

where [92,34,92,34,36,73, 56.......huge image data here] is actual image data in json.

but when i send same request data from c++ it looks like

> "{\"Image\": ÉGÉìÉRÅ[ÉfÉBÉ.........data}"

so here I am getting an error while deserializing the json data using

```
InputData requestData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputData>(jsonData);
```

why am i not able to deserialize the data back to object here when request comes from c++ ?

could you please advise me a way to send this image data as string to the wcf service in C++ where the service could successfully deserialize the data back to the object.

is there a way that i can convert my image data something like  this [92,34,92,34,........] in C++ so that that server can deserialize the data properly (I may be wrong).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

wcf use `DataContract` in order to serialize. but you tried to serialize the input with `newtonsoft`. if you want to serialize the input you can use this method:

```
public static string ToJSON<T>(this T obj) where T : class
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

i strongly suggest in order to avoid this kind of problems use base64 instead of byte array.